# React-Admin: How do I handle an input source on a list of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

In `react-admin`, I have an `input` whose source is a list of objects.

```js
<CheckboxGroupInput  source="binded_cameras" choices={choices}/>
```

The `binded_cameras` list looks like this:

```
"binded_cameras": [
    {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "Cam 1",
       "url": "dummyurl.com"
    },
    {
       "id": 4,
       "name": "Cam 2",
       "url": "dummyurl.com"
     }
]
```

I am trying to get only the list of `id` to deal with.
I tried `binded_cameras.id` but of course it did not work.
**How do I manipulate this list of objects, and generate only a list of ids?**

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Do you want to only pass the `list of ids` as the `source`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I found a solution by modifying the incoming data, but I'd appreciate knowing how to do that on reactjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since React-admin uses react-final-form, you can it's use parse() and format() functions to transform the input value when saving to and loading from the record, just pass them as props to Input, in this case CheckboxGroupInput:

Mnemonic for the two functions:

parse(): input -> record

format(): record -> input

```
<CheckboxGroupInput 
    source="binded_cameras" 
    choices={choices}
    parse={ids => ids.map(id => ({id}))}
    format={bindedCameras => bindedCameras.map(b => b.id)}
/>
```

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#transforming-input-value-tofrom-record